# Create a function to return a value from an asynchronous query

Tags: node.js, aql

I have a AQL query and the query works fine. Instead of printing out the result in the console. How can I get the value(result) of this query into a function ?

1.I hope this question is not too vague

example query

```js
db.query(aqlQuery `
                 LET startVertex = (FOR doc IN spec
                 FILTER doc.serial_no == '"123456abcde"'
                 LIMIT 2
                 RETURN doc
                 )[0]

                FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to
                RETURN v.ip`, {
  bindVar1: 'value',
  bindVar2: 'value',
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log("doc" + res._result);
})
```

**console output :**

- doc,192.168.72.237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap this code in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function that returns query results, and use it with [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword:

```
async function dbQuery(/* your params */) {
    const res = await db.query(/* your query */);
    return res._result;
}

// usage inside another async function
const result = await dbQuery(/* params */);
```

Comment: if you dont mind..,can you tell me what you mean by params in this context

Comment: it should me something like this ., dBQuery(res, req) ? Is that right ?

Comment: it throws an Unexpected Identifier error: await dbQuery();

Comment: `params` is whatever parameters you prefer to pass to this function, it is a matter of design. It could be a query string, for example. Regarding the error, you probably didn't use the call inside another `async` function. Please follow the links in my answer to learn more.

Comment: yes I get it..,I have used nothing for instance..,then I even declared dbQuery(); at the end of the file..still there is an Unexpected Identifier error